# Confluence gives me an old version to edit - page corruption

Tags: confluence

I have a Confluence page where I need to change some data. But when I hit `edit`, the page that loads into the editor is an old version, missing some of the content that was there a second ago in view-mode. I cannot have that vanish, I need to build on top of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My admin says it's some kind of corruption. While there is obviously something wrong with the server, I need to do my job and so I found a workaround:

In view-mode, open the page's menu and select `copy`. You will get to an editor containing the current version of the page that is corrupt. Select all and copy that to the clipboard and discard the duplicate. Go back to the corrupt original, hit `edit` and paste the up-to-date version from the clipboard. Save, then apply your changes as usual.